# Parsing updated collection content, hiding new model view instances

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a Backbone view which represents a collection. When this collection is synced with the server, and new models are added to the collection, I would like to hide all the view instances that represent these new models in the collection, whilst continuing to display the old models' view instances. How can I do this?

Comment: You could disconnect the rendering after the page loads the first time (as you may have wired to an event to render the collection), or mark the ones that rendered originally as being the "old" models and only render them. Or, you could change your rendering code to not trigger from a `reset`/`add`. There are probably other reasonable options as well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a `Marionette.CollectionView` or `Marionette.CompositeView` here, right? That being the case, you are trying to prevent these from showing the newly added models, when the come back from the server and are added to your collection, right?

I can see a few different ways of doing this, most of which begin at the same place: a collection that filters based on an attribute that tells you whether or not to show the model.  You would need to have some piece of data on the models that tells you wether to show them or not... I'm not sure what this would look like off-hand, but once you have the logic set up for this, I think the rest of it becomes easier.

### A Proxy Collection

My preferred method of handling this in the CompositeView or CollectionView would be to create the view instance with a proxy collection - one that is filtered based on the value to show or hide the models.

I've talked about proxy collections before, and I have a working JSFiddle to show how to build them, here: http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/7tvzF/

You would set up a filtered collection like this, and then send the filtered collection to your actual view instance:

```
var filtered = new FilteredCollection(myOriginalCollection);
filtered.filter({
  showThisOne: true
});

var view = new MyCompositeView({
  collection: filtered
});

myOriginalCollection.fetch();
```

From here, it comes down to how you want to manage the filtering and fetch/sync of the original collection. But I think the over-all solution hinges on the proxy/decorator collection and being able to filter the collection down to only the list of items that you want.

Comment: This looks like a good solution. Thanks Derick. What I ended up doing was using `collection.fetch` with the `update: true` and `remove: false` options, to get the collection to trigger `add` and `change` events instead of `resetting`. Then, as the `add` event was triggered, I checked whether the date of the model was newer than that of the newest in the previous collection. If it was, I applied an attribute to filter it. What do you think to this method?

Comment: I should add that I preferred `add` and `change` events because it keeps state, whereas with Marionette, `reset` on a collection will re-render the view.

Answer (score 0):

Views in Bbone are not automatically updated when the underlying model/collection is changed. You have to explicitly listen for events: change/destroy for models and add/change/remove/reset for collections and call render().

As `WiredPrairie` suggests, if you've registered during view initialization for example to listenTo() any of these events and explicitly render(), you can always use stopListening() to reverse the effect.

An alternative, in case it's a one-of case of suppressing the view from showing the changes, is to check manually in your view's render() which models have been changed and use the previous state of the changed attributes to avoid showing the new values. Check out: `model.hasChanged()` and `model.previousAttributes()` as well as the `options.previousModels` in case of a collection `reset`.